# use of "not on purpose"

Tags: expressions, word-usage

I was told that "not on purpose" cannot be used in the middle of a sentence. For example:

> I was showering and, not on purpose, I participated in the #icebucketchallenge.

I am aware of the fact that there are more elegant expressions such as unwillingly, unwittingly etc etc but my question is: is the above correct? Am I allowed to use "not on purpose" in such a way?

I know there is no language police but there are, seemingly, rules. I posted a sentence in a forum with this expression and I was told it is incorrect to use it this way.

Comment: There is no such thing as language police. If you said it, and they understood it, it's fine.

Comment: @DanBron http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_police

Comment: @WayfaringStranger, fine, "no such thing as *English* language police", you damn copper ;)

Comment: While it's not a construction that you'd use in very formal writing, there's really nothing wrong with this. if the aside (the "not on purpose" part) had been surrounded by em-dashes rather than commas, it might have seemed a little bit more idiomatic.

Comment: There also arises the question of whether or not one should worry about the formalities of grammar in any sentence that includes a hash tag.

Answer (score 1):

you could also use 'accidentally' or 'unintentionally' instead of 'not on purpose'

Answer (score 0):

Shove a 'though' on the front of it, and you are fine.

```
I was showering and, though not on purpose, I participated in the #icebucketchallenge.
```

So I would say it is also just fine elliptically omitting the preposition.  Since you set it off as a subordinate phrase, the contradistinction that the 'though' imparts is already implied.

It would also be reasonably expected if you moved the phrase after the verb.

```
I was showering and I participated, not on purpose, in the #icebucketchallenge.
```

Slightly better if you set it off as an intruding sentence fragment.

```
I was showering and I participated -- not on purpose -- in the #icebucketchallenge.
```

So there are many ways of making this sound smoother, but they are all window-dressing.  It is  fine as it is.